# Simple mod_rewritten url adds trailing slash and shows error page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a simple .htaccess file that has the following code:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php [L]
```

Along with this, in the root directory, I have several files (`home.php`, `about.php`, `games.php`, `email.php`, and `search-me.php`) that all should display as `mywebsite.com/home` or `mywebsite.com/email` etc... `home.php`, `about.php`, and `email.php` all work, but for some odd reason, `games.php` and `search-me.php` add a trailing slash to the end of the url and show an error page:

[image: 403 Forbidden]

`games.php` has nothing special about it except that it has several `<iframes>` and *LOTS* of javascript, which makes it a bit slower.

`search-me.php` uses both `$_GET` and `$_POST`, depending on which submit button was pressed on the previous page. For this page, it shows the trailing slash before the `?` and variables, but shows the same error page.

Does anyone know why this is? Let me know if you need more information. I'm trying to think of everything that could be causing it, but the fact that it does it to `games.php`, which has nothing different on it than `home.php` or `about.php` makes it seem like it isn't because of the global variable input (`$_GET` and `$_POST`).

**Edit:** It seems that I have both a directory called `games/` and `search-me/`, which is of course why the error is generated. So, my question now is, is it possible to have a directory and a file with the same name, or is it always going to cause errors?

Comment: Do you by any chance have actual directories named `games` and `search-me` on the same level as well …?

Comment: I sure hope I never told anyone I know how to code! You hit the nail on the head! I have both those directories. So, the question now is is there a way to skip over directories, or do I have to rename them? It would be nice if I didn't have to rename the `search-me/` directory...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Having an error with my site so I can't try it yet.